# how to embed variable name in regex

Tags: c#

I'm doing some regex and here's the following working expression in perl

```
$_ =~ /^([^_]+)_[^,]+,"$from_date\-[\d\/]+","[\d\/]*",
                 "([^"]*)","([^"]*)","([^"]*)","[^"]+"$/x
```

used to match the line with 07/10/2013-07/11/2013 somewhere in there, so for ex. here from_date = 07/10/2013.

Now I want to replicate the same thing in C# but C# does not have the $ sign so from_date is not getting read as a variable.  How would I change the above, ie how do I embed an existing variable name in regex so it doesn't get read as a string. I tried some quotes and using + sign but it didn't work

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are correct, was thrown a bit by the title.

Answer (score 3):

Just concatenate the string.

```
var rx = new Regex("^([^_]+)_[^,]+," + fromDate + "…the rest…");
```

Alternatively, use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). I tend to find this more readable:

```
var rx = new Regex(string.Format("^([^_]+)_[^,]+,{0}…the rest…", fromDate);
```

Comment: if (Regex.IsMatch(result, "^([^_]+)_[^,]+,"+from_date+"-[\\d\\/]+\",\"[\\d\\/]*\",\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\",\"[^\"]+\"$"))                     I have tried this and it didnt find it

Comment: @user2521358 That’s quite unreadable. Use a literal string in C#, then you don’t need to escape quotes and other backslashes: `@"this"is\a string";` instead of `"this\"is\\a string";`

Comment: I'm getting quite confused,